# How do I make a brick die and then blows up afterwards?

Tags: roblox

I am trying to make a part die, but I don't exactly know how to go about that. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please familiarize yourself with [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask questions that will inspire prompt, high-quality answers. Remember, the effort that you put into the question indicates your respect for the time of the people whose help you are requesting.

Comment: A standard part in Roblox doesn't have a 'die' attribute associated with it. What do you mean by 'die'?

Answer (score 1):

"a part die", By that you mean, something like, making it dissapear? remove it? destroy it? make it explode and dissapear?

Don't worry, we'll get to that right now.

---

### Making it dissapear

If you want to make a part just dissapear, or maybe something more fancy, like making it slowly become transparent or dissapear,you can use this codes.

Also, try to learn from this codes! :)

**Not-very-fancy way**

```
local part = nil; -- Change nil to the part object
part:Destroy();
```

Yes, that's all for doing it in the "not-very-fancy way!"

**Fancy way**

```
local part = nil; -- Same thing here!
local alpha = 30; -- Change this to the number of ticks before the part turning completely transparent.
for i = 1, alpha do
    part.Transparency = part.Transparency + 1/30;
    wait();
end;
part.Transparency = 1;
```

Yes, that's all! it's quite simple to do these things. Now, let's pass to the next methods!

---

### Removing it

This is the easiest method, it actually is the same as the first I shown to you.

```
local part = nil; -- Change nil to the part object
part:Remove();
```

---

### Destroying it

This method, again, is the same as the one shown up, just that we replace :Remove() with :Destroy(). :Destroy() is generally more used, perhaps because of it's efficency.

```
local part = nil; -- Change nil to the part object
part:Destroy();
```

Doing all this is quite easy, even if you haven't got alot of experience in RBLX_Lua, or Lua.

---

### Making it explode and dissapear

Okay, so, there are two ways of doing this. Both create a explosion, but one makes the part fade off with time, cause, why not?

**Making it explode and then dissapear only**

```
local part = nil; -- Same here, change this variable to the part object.
local ex = Instance.new("Explosion", workspace);
ex.Position = part.Position;

part:Destroy();
```

**Making it explode and slowly dissapear**

```
local part = nil; -- Again, change nil to the actual part object.
local ex = Instance.new("Explosion", workspace);
ex.Position = part.Position;

for i = 1, 30 do
    part.Transparency = part.Transparency + 1/30;
    wait();
end;
part:Destroy();
```

That should be all you need to know for now, I tryed to make it simple and understandable as possible, considering you're quite new to Roblox Lua, I hope you learn from this.

Also, remember there are multiple, nearly infinite ways of doing the same thing, but I presented to you the ones which are simplest, and shortest (in lines).

Also, welcome to stack overflow community! Hope you have a great time here!